# Lollipop Android Emulator Recent Apps not showing screenshots

Tags: android, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working to prevent Lollipop from displaying screenshots of our secure application in the recent apps screen (square button).

However in my emulator when I browse to the recent apps page it does not show any apps screenshots:

[The screenshot isn't displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHEgo.jpg)

Obviously I can't prove that the screen isn't shown if no screens are shown.
Is there a way to turn this on in the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which method are you using? Android has a built in solution using

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

This would be set in each activity, or a single activity if all your activities have a shared parent.

The result would be a black square where the screenshot of the app would normally be.

Comment: This is what i'm planning on implementing, however the emulator doesn't seem to be displaying any activities secure or not.

Comment: I have made it worked on GenyMotion emulator. Are you using the default Android emulator?

Comment: Yeah standard Android one.

Comment: Downloaded the Genymotion emulator and the recent app screen works.

As a side note setting this flag does as explained.